# Getting the http request headers in the frontend

Tags: javascript, http, networking, window

I would like to see the http request headers in the frontend. I've been digging around in the browser's window object and saw the following:

```
new window.Response().headers.values()
```

I am aware that I can see the request headers on the backend server and then just send it as a response to the frontend, but I don't want to make the extra call instead I want to use the window object or something similar. Is such anything possible?

Comment: You can use response from the `fetch` method if you want. The `response.headers` will give you that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can get response headers like this. The [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) class instance that fetch returns is an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

```js
fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds').then(function(response) {
  response.headers.forEach(console.log);
});
```

Comment: Possible to *just* return the headers and avoid a full 177KB payload in this example?